# QGIS Zonal Statistics returns empty?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics

Does anyone familiar with the QGIS Zonal Statistics tool know why stats calculations might return empty?

Inputs

1. DEM for South Carolina: http://dnr.sc.gov/GIS/descdem.html
2. A vector shapefile: https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.improvz.com/gis/Archive.zip

Desired result: Zonal Statistics calculates elevation on all shapes.

Actual result: Zonal Statistics plugin returns empty values for all fields

[image: Parcels and DEM loaded]
[image: Zonal Stats plugin prompt]
[image: Zonal Stats calculating]
[image: No elevation stats are calculated]

QGIS 2.8 on MacOSX.

Comment: Try upgrading to QGIS 3.2 and re-test. There's been lots of fixes since 2.8

Comment: tks, @ndawson Upgrade plus the suggestions below fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file "CAD_PARCEL_MP have some topology error (check with menu Vector >"topology checker).

I fix it with the processing tool "fix geometry" in QGIS 3.2, and than it seems working

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting to know that `fix geometries` solved this issue, thanks to [Volta](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93170/volta).

My suggestion is (was) to reproject the polygon layer to match with the DEM layer; since most FAQ about `Zonal Statistics` are related to different CRSs between raster and polygon layers.

A quick test, reprojecting the `CAD_PARCEL_MP` to EPSG: 2029 `*NAD27(76) UTM zone 17N*` looks OK.

[image]

... an alternative option, just in case :)

---

**Update**

Seeing the comment by [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson), my last line `just in case` should be `just in case the work has to be done in pre-QGIS 3`. The CRS issue is gone now.

Comment: tks, @Kazuhito...helpful!

Comment: This is no longer required in QGIS 3.2 - if you have different CRS between the raster and vector, it will automatically be handled correctly.

Comment: @ndawson, I am not sure about your comment. I had this issue today (QGIS 3.16) and setting both: the shape and the raster to the same CRS was the only thing that made it work for me