# $area gives NULL for some polygons in QGIS's Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, field-calculator, attribute-table, area

I have the map of Cambodia(map) and the economic land concessions(elc). In trying to find the proportion of district covered by land concesions, I need the area variable. But when I create the variable as `$area`, there are some entries that are `NULL` - it is the case for both layers. I have tried 'fix geometries.' It mostly fixed the problem for elc layer but still is `NULL` for one layer as following. Smaller piece and the bigger piece are seperate entries but area is calculated only for the small area.

[image]

The area calculation issue is not fixed at all for the elc layer. What is the next thing I could try to fix this problem?

I am following the steps from this link:
[Finding overlay percentage between two polygon shapefiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293050/finding-overlay-percentage-between-two-polygon-shapefiles)

Data using:
GEO2_KH (Cambodia shapefile)
https://international.ipums.org/international/gis_harmonized_2nd.shtml
ELCs: All economic land concessions shapefile
https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/economiclandconcessions

Comment: Please add the projection your are using.

Comment: @mapperz, I am using EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Short Answer

you have to re-project the shapefile to [EPSG:3148](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3148/) - Indian 1960 / UTM zone 48N

### Long Answer

1. Load the shapefile
2. Left click the shapefile in `Layers` pallet
3. Go to `Export > Save feature as`
4. Save as `ESRI Shapefile` with giving a new `File Name` and setting the coordinate system `CRS` as  **EPSG:3148** (EPSG:3148- Indian 1960 / UTM zone 48N)

[image]

5. Then go to `Attribute Table` of the newly created shapefile
6. Go to Field Calculator
7. And enter `$area` in the **Expression Field** while giving a name to the column with data type **int** *(if you prefer **int64** over **int** give **int64** but not required)*
   [image]

then all the shapes with a positive geometry will display an area.

[image]

but areas with **unknown geometry** will not display any area

[image]

Comment: Thanks Uditha! Could I ask why re-projection was necessary?

Comment: I have tried several methods but this was the method gave the answer. if I found another method  I will update you ASAP

Comment: Thank you so much, Uditha!

Comment: As explanation, `$area` returns the area calculated *in the units of the CRS* being used. EPSG:4326 is unprojected, in degrees latitude and longitute. So the answer is in "square degrees" (it's actually a bit more complicated) with one "square degree" being about 10000 sq km on the ground. I expect some of your areas were close to zero at this scale. When you reproject to a better CRS, the calculation takes place in square meters.

Comment: Yes @Houska that was my initial idea as well. And i tried to find if there are errors with in the original shape file and for several of them yes there were. So I intentionally reprojected it to meters.

Comment: Good Answer, thanks for taking time for this detailed answer,

Comment: What do you mean by a "positive geometry"? I have the same problem, as some polygons return NULL areas, but I already had my data projected (I'm using UTM Zone 36N)

Comment: here with in this shapefile there are entries where the geometry had been deleted. but the attribute table entry is there. therefore, for all the attribute table entries with geometries I had noted them as **Positive Geometries**. 

@Hany Nagaty can you give me more details where I can probe in to your problem like this. with in the area column is it specifically stated as NULL or stated as 0