# $area is NULL for over-wrapping geometry

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, area

This question follows from [$area gives NULL for some polygons in QGIS's Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385397/area-gives-null-for-some-polygons-in-qgiss-field-calculator). New question asks the same question as to why some area variables appear NULL. But the problem was resolved for one layer but not the other.

All $areas are found except for the polygon in the screenshot. The larger polygon and smaller polygon are over-wrapped but are separate entries. Area for smaller entry is found but not the bigger one. I tried fixing geometries but it does not help. Please let me know how I can proceed.

I am using the layer, all economic concessions (English) from the link: https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/economiclandconcessions

[image]

Comment: I am working on this as well. give me some time to go through this. if I found any solution I will answer. this is more interesting than the previous one.

Comment: @uditha, Thank you so much.

Comment: it is probably an invalid polygon

Comment: yes sir, several of them are invalid because the attribute table entries are nor accompanied with geometries @Ian Turton . But in several of them have area values exceeding whole number integer maximum limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

since the `$area` calculated exceeding the value of the displayable limit of the `whole number integer` with in field calculator please use **output field type** as `whole number integer 64 bit` with maximum output field length of `21`

(**whole number integer 64 bit and 21 field size is a must**)

### Long Answer

Please refer the previous answer [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385397/area-gives-null-for-some-polygons-in-qgiss-field-calculator) for the CRS Change and all up to step 4

1. go to the `Attribute Table` of the newly created shapefile
2. Go to Field Calculator
3. And enter `$area` in the **Expression Field** while giving a name to the column with data type **whole number integer 64 bit** (whole number integer 64 bit and 21 field size is a must)
4. then give the `output field length` as 21 (maximum possible)

[image]

5. and click `ok`
6. your attribute table should look like this

[image]

again as previous areas with **unknown geometry** will not display any area

[image]

Comment: or create a float number field, as it's country areas, just divide the area by 1 000 000 to have square kilometers : `round($area / 1000000, 2)`.

Comment: @J.Monticolo yes, this is also can be done. with this we can go with **whole number integer** as well.