# Calculating proportion of area covered by another layer - not just the intersection

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, area

This is a follow up question from [$area gives NULL for some polygons in QGIS's Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385397/area-gives-null-for-some-polygons-in-qgiss-field-calculator) and [$area is NULL for over-wrapping geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385433/area-is-null-for-over-wrapping-geometry).

I have a map of Cambodia at district level (dist) and economic land concession (elc). I am trying to calculate the proportion of district that is occupied by the economic land concession. I have tried the following:

1. created area for `elc` layer
2. for dist layer,
   `100*intersecting_geom_sum('elc','area_elc')/$area`

Problem is, there are some districts that have over 100% coverage because the `elc` layers in these districts have outrageously large area calculated.

[image]

I have used the following data, projected them into EPSG:3148, set the output field length as 21 for area calculation as advised. I also ran fix geometry for `elc` layer afterwards.

How can I correctly calculate the area for these districts.

*** ADDED

I have found that for a small district, area of one big chunk of `elc` that cross the district and other district was used- instead of part of `elc` that is within district. Attached as picture below:

[image: Area of district is 913 km^2]

[image: Area of elc is 3336 km^2]

When I take the intersection, it works to cut them correctly. How could I possibly correct this problem?

Data using:
GEO2_KH (Cambodia shapefile) https://international.ipums.org/international/gis_harmonized_2nd.shtml

ELCs: All economic land concessions shapefile https://data.opendevelopmentcambodia.net/dataset/economiclandconcessions

Comment: @UdithaHerath, Could you please have a look at this at your convenience? I'd appreciate any advice on this. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you keep the area as square meters and not convert it in square kilometers ? I think it's more meaning full when you work with country, district data. You can create a float number field.

Comment: Try `area($geometry)` for the calculations.

Comment: check that fix geometry actually produced valid geometries

Comment: @J.Monticolo Hi, I have converted it to square kilometers. It is helpful to know what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @Erik. Thank you, I have tried using the alternative measure.

Comment: Hi, @IanTurton. I have tried fixing geometry for both layers. To me, it seems valid. But when calculating the proportion of area covered, it uses the whole chunk instead of proportion. Any idea how it may be fixed?

Comment: just because it looks ok doesn't mean it is valid - check with isValid()

Comment: @IanTurton, I have tried IsValid() and they are valid geometries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to calculate that proportion and It worked for me. May be you did something wrong with those areas. The issue here is that a single `dist` can have several `elc` intersections.

Here is the result:
[image]

Here I describe you the process:

1. Correct geometries (otherwise the intersection tool doesn't work).
2. Intersection (Union) of the layers. This layer will serve as a future dissolved layer with the `elc` area within each `dist`.
3. Filter the layer removing those polygons with null `fid`(keep just elc).
4. Dissolve by `ADMIN_NAME`. This will make a single `elc` área.
5. Calculate the área of `elc`.
6. Join layers: `dist` joined to the dissolved layer by `ADMIN_NAME`.
7. Calculate the percentage of `dist` covered with `elc`.

Here some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!