# Intersecting geometry sum - sharing the boundary count as intersection

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, intersection, area

This question stems from [Calculating proportion of area covered by another layer - not just the intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385453/calculating-proportion-of-area-covered-by-another-layer-not-just-the-intersect)

I have narrowed down the problem.

I am attempting to find the percent of district layer(layer D) covered by another layer B.

In the picture layer B consist of 1+2+3.

When creating the intersection between layer D and B, it splits them into 1,2,3.

I create the interaction, find area for each interaction, and in the district layer, create

100* intersecting_geom_sum('Intersection','area_intersection')/$area

The ideal end result is area of 1 / area of D.

But it calculates area of 1+2+3/ are of D.

I have checked that the geometries are valid, but I think the interaction command is the problem.

When sharing the boundary counts as intersection.

How do I restrict it such that sharing boundary does not count as intersection?

[image: Calculating proportion of area of 1 over area of district D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlap analysis solved the problem.